# How to override createView to save multiple data entry

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, django-generic-views

using **CreateView** class, I want to save multiple data entries.
example inputs:

item is "apple,banana,carrots" 
    location is "location 1"

I want to save them to database like this:
    [apple, location 1]
    [banana, location 1]
    [carrots, location 1]

```
#model.py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10)

#forms.py
class InventoryCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 8,                                                      
                                                       'cols': 14}))
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory

#views.py
class InventoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Inventory
    form_class = InventoryCreateForm
```

Thank you

Comment: Why forcing yourself to use `CreateView`? It's not suppose to be used instead of FBV wherever possible. Just use functional view. Also, in your case, seems like [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) should be useful to manage items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm already using FBV for this implementation, and i'm trying to explore GCBV, that's why i'm trying to utilize createView.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the "form_valid()" method used by the createview.

You then need to read in the form data

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    foo = self.object.bar #your data is in the object
```

Then because you are using a textfield you need to somehow split the data passed into the form and loop over those values. Ideally you will want a list of items ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
then take the location out of the list and store that into a variable that can be used later on *location_variable*.

Once you have the data in the form you want you then need to instantiate the Inventory model

```
from foo.models import Inventory #import at the top of your file  

for item is list:
    inventory = Inventory()
    inventory.item = item
    inventory.location = location_variable
    inventory.save()
```

I hope this answer can help you in some way, if you would like further details on Class based view, visit [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk) where all of the information for each view is listed.

Otherwise you can look in the django [Form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/) for a more suitable form to use.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this helps anyone else who comes to this page.

Here is what I did:

```
class TrainingBulkCreateForm(ModelForm):
    # todo: could we make the original user object a multiple choice field instead?
    extra_user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=True), required=True)

    class Meta(object):
        model = Training
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        users = request.POST.getlist('extra_user')
        if users:
            # modify request.POST data then re-save the additional users

            for user in users:
                # Need to copy the data because the initial QueryDict is immutable data
                postdata_copy = request.POST.copy()
                postdata_copy['user'] = user
                form2 = TrainingBulkCreateForm(postdata_copy)

                form2.save()

        return result
```

I have my `item` field (mine is `user`) split into two form fields - the original `item` which is 1 object like `apple`.

Then I also have `extra_user` as a second form field. This takes multiple objects like `[banana, carrots]`

In the view I invoke the `super().post(...)` to save the initial `apple` object.
Then I check for the `extra_user` field to see if there are multiple foods. If there are extras, I copy the immutable QueryDict object `request.POST` as `postdata_copy`.
Then I modify `postdata_copy` so instead of having `apple` we replace with `banana`. (This basically just duplicates the `apple` form into a new copy with `banana` and re-saves the form). Then we loop again and replace `apple` with `carrots`.

Note that my Form object uses `ModelMultipleChoiceField` for `extra_user` object. This has better data integrity than typing in raw text.